# Form validation message is not displayed for flatpickr field?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, ajaxform

I am building a custom contact form in a WordPress theme. I have been trying to show the validation error message for a Flatpickr date field however it is not working. I have even tried `form.find('input[type=hidden]').val()` to get the value, however it is still not working.

Datepicker field values getting submitted to the database, only the validation error is not displaying.

Since, I am new to jquery, simpler solution is expected.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    // Date picker
    $("#date").flatpickr({
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y",
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
        minDate: "today",
        maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(30), // 14 days from now
        "disable": [
            function(date) {
                // return true to disable
                return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
    
            }
        ],
        "locale": {
            "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
        }
    });
    
    /* contact form submission */
    $('#someForm').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.was-validated').removeClass('.was-validated');

        var form = $(this),
            name = form.find('#name').val(),
            email = form.find('#email').val(),
            service = form.find('#service').val(),
            date = form.find('input[type=hidden]').val(),
            message = form.find('#message').val(),
            ajaxurl = form.data('url');


        if (name === '') {
            $('#name').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }

        if( email === '' ){
            $('#email').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }
        
        if( service === '' ){
            $('#service').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }
        
        // This bit of code is not working.
        if( date === '' ){
            $('#date').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }

        $('#submitButton').html('Processing...');

        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.ajax({
            
            url : ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                
                name : name,
                email : email,
                service: service,
                aptDate: aptDate,
                message : message,
                action: 'save_user_contact_form'
                
            },
            error : function( response ){
                $('#formErrorMessage').modal('show');
                $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            success : function( response ){
                if( response == 0 ){
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#formErrorMessage').modal('show');
                        $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    },1500);

                } else {
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#formSuccessMessage').modal('show');
                        $('.col-lg-2').removeClass('was-validated');
                        $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled').val('');
                    },1500);

                }
            }
            
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it working. I tried to find answer to my problem on Google and fortunately I reached [this post](https://www.vic-l.com/how-to-use-html-validation-on-flatpickr/) by Victor Leong. While his solution is based on the calendar states onOpen and onClose, we can also use it for onReady.

Add below code to flatpickr options

```
        allowInput: true,
        onReady: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            $(instance.altInput).prop('readonly', false);
        },
```

This bit of code will remove the `readonly` attribute from input field. Please check [Victor's article](https://www.vic-l.com/how-to-use-html-validation-on-flatpickr/) for more information. He has explained it nicely.

**This is my complete working code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Date picker
    $("#aptdate").flatpickr({
        allowInput: true,
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y",
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
        minDate: "today",
        maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(30), // 30 days from now
        "disable": [
            function(date) {
                // return true to disable dates based on days
                return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
            }
        ],
        "locale": {
            "firstDayOfWeek": 1 // start week on Monday
        },

        // Remove readonly attribute from the date input field
        onReady: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            $(instance.altInput).prop('readonly', false);
        },

    });
    
    /* contact form submission */
    $('#someForm').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.was-validated').removeClass('.was-validated');

        var form = $(this),
            name = form.find('#name').val(),
            email = form.find('#email').val(),
            service = form.find('#service').val(),
            aptDate = form.find('#aptdate').val(),
            message = form.find('#message').val(),
            ajaxurl = form.data('url');

        if (name === '') {
            $('#name').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }

        if( email === '' ){
            $('#email').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }
        
        if( service === '' ){
            $('#service').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }

        if ( aptDate === '' ) {
            $('#aptdate').parent('.col-lg-2').addClass('was-validated');
            return;
        }

        $('#submitButton').html('Processing...');

        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.ajax({
            
            url : ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                
                name : name,
                email : email,
                service: service,
                aptDate: aptDate,
                message : message,
                action: 'save_user_contact_form'
                
            },
            error : function( response ){
                $('#formErrorMessage').modal('show');
                $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled');
            },
            success : function( response ){
                if( response == 0 ){
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#formErrorMessage').modal('show');
                        $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled');
                    },1500);

                } else {
                    
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#formSuccessMessage').modal('show');
                        $('.col-lg-2').removeClass('was-validated');
                        $('#submitButton').html('Submit');
                        form.find('input, button, textarea, select').removeAttr('disabled').val('');
                    },1500);

                }
            }
            
        });

    });

});
```

If there is a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the next element of the date, because `flatpckr` generate new element to save the value.

```
const date= $('#date');

if (date.attr("class").includes("is-invalid")) {
  date.next().removeClass("is-invalid");
  date.next().addClass("is-invalid");
} else {
  date.next().removeClass("is-invalid");
}
```